# Java, calling methods and override

Tags: java, overriding

I have to design a class that consists of 2 subs-classes. Let's say A and B and B has 2 subs-classes too. This part is really not important because I did all this with different names.

I am struggling with trying to run my code. I have the code but I am getting 2 errors. I can't figure out how to fix it.

The errors are the following:

> aaa1.java:147: cannot find symbol
>       symbol  : constructor Employee(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
>       location: class Employee
>                       super(name, address, phone, email);
>                       ^
>       aaa1.java:179: cannot find symbol
>       symbol  : constructor Employee(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
>       location: class Employee
>                       super(name, address, phone, email);

My code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class aaa1 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Person p = new Person("J11h", "123 ABC St", "908-123-456", "asdf123@gmail.com");
        Student s = new Student("222se1h", "123 ABC St", "908-123-456", "asdf123@gmail.com", 1);
        Date date = new Date();
        Employee e = new Employee("wewesh", "123 ABC St", "908-123-456", "asdf123@gmail.com", "123", 2000.00, date);
        Faculty f = new Faculty("eewrr", "123 ABC St", "908-123-456", "asdf123@gmail.com", "1pm - 3pm", "Head of the department");
        Staff st = new Staff("rrereh", "123 ABC St", "908-123-456", "asdf123@gmail.com", "Assistant");
        System.out.println(p.toString());
        System.out.println(s.toString());
        System.out.println(e.toString());
        System.out.println(f.toString());
        System.out.println(st.toString());
    }
}

class Person {
    //A person has a name, address, phone number, and email address.
    String name;
    String address;
    String phone;
    String email;

    public Person(String name, String address, String phone, String email) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress(){
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address){
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getPhone(){
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone){
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email){
        this.email = email;
    }

    //Overriding
    public String toString(){
        return "The person's information is "+name+ ", " +address+ ", " +phone+ ", " +email;
    }
}

class Student extends Person{
    //A student has a class status
    //(freshman,sophomore, junior, or senior).
    //Define the status as a constant.
    final int freshman =1;
    final int sophomore =2;
    final int junior=3;
    final int senior=4;
    int status;

    public Student(String name, String address, String phone, String email, int status) {
        super(name, address, phone, email);
        this.status = status;
    }

    public int getStatus(){
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(int status){
        this.status = status;
    }

    //Overriding
    public String toString(){
        return "The student's information is: " +super.toString()+ "," + status;
    }
}

class Employee extends Person{
    //An employee has an office, salary, and date hired.
    String office;
    double salary;
    java.util.Date dateHired;

    public Employee(String name, String address, String phone, String email, String office, double salary, Date dateHired){
        super(name, address, phone, email);
        this.office = office;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.dateHired = dateHired;
    }

    public String getOffice(){
        return office;
    }

    public void setOffice(String office){
        this.office = office;
    }

    public double getSalary(){
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary){
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public void setDateHired(Date dateHired){
        this.dateHired = dateHired;
    }

    //Overriding
    public String toString(){
        return "The Employee's information is: " +super.toString()+ ", " +office+ ", " +salary+ ", " +dateHired;
    }
}

class Faculty extends Employee{
    //A faculty member has office hours and a rank.
    String officeHours;
    String rank;

    public Faculty(String name, String address, String phone, String email, String officeHours, String rank){
        super(name, address, phone, email);
        this.officeHours = officeHours;
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    public String getOfficeHours(){
        return officeHours;
    }

    public void setOfficeHours(String officeHours){
        this.officeHours = officeHours;
    }

    public String getRank(){
        return rank;
    }

    public void setRank(String rank){
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    //Overriding
    public String toString(){
        return "The faculty's information is: " +super.toString()+ ", " + officeHours + ", " + rank;
    }
}

class Staff extends Employee{
    //A staff member has a title
    String title;

    public Staff(String name, String address, String phone, String email, String title){
        super(name, address, phone, email);
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title = title;
    }

    //Overriding
    public String toString(){
        return "The staff's information is: " +super.toString()+ "," + title;
    }
}
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Please make a comment which indicate the line number of error.

Comment: Have you tried putting the two classes into separate files?

Comment: @Razib The error occurs in the class Employee. It is within the constructor super. This section:
"public Employee(String name, String address, String phone, String email, String office, double salary, Date dateHired){
                super(name, address, phone, email);"

Comment: Use `@Override` instead of `//Overriding` - the former actually has semantic meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Employee` class contains a constructor with the following parameters:

```
public Employee(String name, String address, String phone, String email, String office, double salary, Date dateHired){
```

And your `Faculty` and `Staff` classes, which extend `Employee`, contain this explicit call to `super`:

```
super(name, address, phone, email);
```

The number of arguments in the call to `super` and the number of arguments in the `Employee` class constructor do not match; you're providing four String arguments when it needs one additional `String`, a `double`, and a `java.util.Date`.

Comment: Thank you. My code is working now.
I would like to give the green check to all you guys but I can't. Your answers was clear and effective. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

`Faculty` - the class at line 147 - extends `Employee`, so you need to invoke a super constructor from `Employee`:

```
public Employee(String name, String address, String phone, String email, String office, double salary, Date dateHired){
```

i.e. you need to pass all of these parameters if you want to instantiate a subclass of `Employee` such as `Faculty`.

Alternatively, you could declare another constructor in `Employee` which takes just those 4 parameters. However, you would then need to decide what to do about the parameters that you have not passed in - do you simply set them to `null`, or do you set them to a safe default? This depends upon your application.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that as you have it extending you need to also include the original constructor, so you have to have the same constructor as a person in the student staff and employee (with an @Override )

even if it just calls super();

so that is a Constructor (string,string,string,string);
Employee(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

You will find the problem if you think a while of:

- What will be the office, salary and hired date for a Faculty or a Staff member?